# How do I get Sinatra to work with HTTPClient?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to create a facade API that receives requests via Sinatra then launches HTTP requests on Github API in the backend.

In my "hello world" script I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'httpclient'
require 'sinatra'

get '/foo' do
    "hello world"
end
```

However, it runs into errors like:

```
$ ./api.rb 
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1408:in `run!': undefined method `run' for HTTP:Module (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
```

I don't understand why this happens.  If I comment out the `require 'httpclient'` line, it works just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

#require 'httpclient'
require 'sinatra'

get '/foo' do
  "hello world"
end

$ ./api.rb 
[2013-06-26 21:43:12] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-06-26 21:43:12] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-05-15) [x86_64-linux]
[2013-06-26 21:43:12] WARN  TCPServer Error: Cannot assign requested address - bind(2)
== Sinatra/1.4.3 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2013-06-26 21:43:12] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=31272 port=4567
```

My guess is that Sinatra is using HTTPClient by itself and some kind of namespace collision is happening.  Is there a way to use HTTPClient and Sinatra at the same time?

OK here is the requested info:

```
$ gem list sinatra httpclient

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

sinatra (1.4.3)

$ gem out sinatra httpclient
bigdecimal (1.1.0 < 1.2.0)
io-console (0.3 < 0.4.2)
json (1.6.8 < 1.8.0)
rdoc (3.12 < 4.0.1)
```

I figured out httpclient version this way:

```
$ locate httpclient.rb
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.3/lib/httpclient.rb
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.3/test/test_httpclient.rb
```

My OS is Fedora 17, though not sure if it matters.

Comment: Sinatra doesn't use HTTPClient. If it did, you wouldn't have to require them separately, and gems would automatically install HTTPClient when you tell it to install Sinatra.

Comment: I just tried this code on Ruby 1.9.3 with Sinatra 1.4.3 and `httpclient` 2.3.3. I wasn't able to replicate the problem. Did you leave something out?

Comment: Can not reproduce that with sinatra (1.4.1) & httpclient (2.3.3). My opinion that's because you use global ruby, and it might have old version of httpclient

Comment: It has nothing to do with a "global" Ruby. It would be in the source code somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I didn't leave anything out; as you can see all I did was to comment out the require 'httpclient' line.  From what I can tell, my httpclient version is 2.3.3.  I'll test it out on a different OS (RHEL6) and see what happens.

Comment: I figured out one solution: `gem install thin`. When I run it on WEBrick I can reproduce it, but on Thin it works as it should. Reason still a mystery though.

Comment: Type `gem list sinatra httpclient` at the command-line. What are the versions you are running? What does `gem out sinatra httpclient` say? Add the responses to the bottom of your question by editing it, not by adding comments.

Comment: Thank you Casper.  It is very much a mystery to me as well.  I'll try out thin.

Comment: More clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777850/mechanize-sinatra-conflict

Comment: I ran the code successfully with Ruby 1.9.3-p429, Sinatra 1.4.3 and HTTPClient 2.3.3.

Comment: @theTinMan ..but did you run on Thin or WEBrick?

Comment: See this https://github.com/nahi/httpclient/issues then read this: https://github.com/nahi/httpclient/issues/169. HTTPClient hasn't been touched in over four months

Comment: WEBrick. Instead of HTTPClient, try OpenURI, Curb or Typhoeus. Instead of WEBrick use Thin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the reason. HTTPClient defines a module named `HTTP`. By default Sinatra looks for Rack handlers with namespace names `HTTP` and `WEBrick`, in that order.

Since the `HTTP` namespace has been defined Sinatra actually thinks it's a Rack handler. I think this is a bug in Sinatra. It should check if the handler responds to `run` before using it.

Anyway the fix is to use Thin, or if you want to use WEBrick then explicitly tell Sinatra to skip the automatic Rack detection by doing:

```
set :server, 'webrick'
```

That will prevent Sinatra from thinking the HTTPClient `HTTP` module is Rack handler.

Comment: +1 Sounds very reasonable for them to do `responds_to(:run)` as a sanity check. Using Thin has advantages too. Good catch!

Comment: You guys are incredible.  Thank you very much for your help!  I'll test it out later today and report back the result.

Comment: Yup, just tested with thin and it worked fine.  Looks like thin is a better webserver anyway, so I can stick with that.  I also learned how to configure Rack application and launch thin with increased timeout value.  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: I ran into this too - when I setup a new env. I didn't realize that I didn't have thin installed. Since sinatra will try to use thin first by default, all I had to do was 'sudo gem install thin' - then startup the app again.