# Ruby/Sinatra app (file) does not run (start)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using: ruby-1.9.3-p392 and sinatra-1.4.3.

when I run my file, I got this errors:

```
/home/belka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@Rails3.2.13/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1408:in `run!': undefined method `run' for HTTP:Module (NoMethodError)

from /home/belka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@Rails3.2.13/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
```

my code is the simplest code for a sinatra newbie (**hello.rb**):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    'Hello World!'
end
```

Comment: Can you show the command you're using to run this? Also, you shouldn't need `require 'rubygems'`, see https://gist.github.com/rtomayko/54177.

Comment: I'm using this command to run my .rb script:    ruby hello.rb

Comment: It looks like you’ve somehow got a module named `HTTP` loaded when you try to start your server. Your problem looks a bit like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334734/how-do-i-get-sinatra-to-work-with-httpclient, although I can’t see how anything like that would happen with the code you’ve posted.

Comment: You could try sandboxing it using Bundler. Add a Gemfile with the only gem being `gem "sinatra"` in it, then run `bundle install --binstubs --path vendor` in the Hello World project's directory. Then try running the script via `bundle exec ruby hello.rb`. If that works then something is wrong with the gems you've got installed in that RVM@Rails gemset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just needed to add this code, and my sinatra app is now alive:

```
set :server, 'webrick'
```

Comment: I think this indicates there is something wrong with your setup, as [this setting is set by default](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__handler_used_for_builtin_web_server) (slightly differently, but still) and should just work.

Comment: what kind of errors in my setup, I just installed the sinatra gem with: `gem install sinatra`

Comment: Is that the only gem installed in that environment/gemset? Sandbox, sandbox, sandbox… ;)

Comment: No ofcourse, I've installed before lot of gems in this environment for example: rails, mechanize, ....

Comment: OK then, there's the first possible problem: interaction of gems. RVM and Bundler make it easy to sandbox your gems, so now I use Bundler to sandbox every new project (as I mentioned in the comments to the question). If you follow that and don't get the error without need the configuration variable, then it's the gems interacting.