# Mechanize + Sinatra + Heroku: App crashed

Tags: heroku, sinatra, mechanize

I created a Sinatra app that uses Mechanize gem. It runs fine locally, but when I deploy it to Heroku it tells me

```
 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" fwd="83.245.232.99" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

even for this minimized code:

```
require "sinatra"
require "rubygems"
require "mechanize"

get '/' do 
  "hi"
end
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the reason.

HTTPClient defines a module named HTTP. By default Sinatra looks for Rack handlers with namespace names HTTP and WEBrick, in that order.

Since the HTTP namespace has been defined Sinatra actually thinks it's a Rack handler. I think this is a bug in Sinatra. It should check if the handler responds to run before using it.

Anyway the fix is to use Thin, or if you want to use WEBrick then explicitly tell Sinatra to skip the automatic Rack detection by doing:

set :server, 'webrick'
That will prevent Sinatra from thinking the HTTPClient HTTP module is Rack handler.

Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334734/how-do-i-get-sinatra-to-work-with-httpclient)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it requires

```
set :server, 'webrick'
```

in my **app.rb** to run with Mechanize without error.