# Ruby/Sinatra OAuth implementation

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, spotify

After running Spotify OAuth I'm getting this:

```
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:MyFavMC Macbook$ ruby spotify_token_swap.rb -o 0.0.0.0
[2015-01-08 22:35:13] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-08 22:35:13] INFO  ruby 2.1.3 (2014-09-19) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 1234 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2015-01-08 22:35:13] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=8834 port=1234
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. That's exactly the standard output you'll get from the service when you run it - if you then go to `http://localhost:1234` on that same machine you should see a "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty" message, which is also correct.

Once running like this, you'll be able to use it with the iOS SDK. However, since it's on `localhost` it won't be accessible from your iOS device - you'll need to put it in a publicly accessible location for that.

Comment: Thank you iKenndac. Where can I find documentation/instructions on using a publicly accessible location? Can I save it to Parse? Anything to point me in the right direction. I would eventually want to publish my app so I'm assuming I'd need to do this.

Comment: It's just a standard Ruby/Sinatra app - Google it and you'll find a ton of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because Sinatra is unable to find the appropriate server. A quick fix is explicitly assigning server to Sinatra (say WEBrick) like this:

```
set :server, 'webrick'
```

You can refer to this SO for detailed explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17335819/3035830

Reference for adding above code: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html